# Using vb.net classes in c#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dll, types

How can I create a type in vb.net and use the type in c#?
I guess I need to compile the vb project and add reference to the dll but have no idea if this is the   right way to do it, or the reference will be valid.
Doing this is not for fun, we have some vb code and we're considering this option.

Comment: Yes,you can make them class library and use them.

Comment: Just add the project to your solution and add a reference. The languages of projects in a solution don't matter.

Comment: @JohnWillemse can they have a common namespace?

Comment: Jon is right, do it just like you had to deal with c# type - create a library and add a reference to it.

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan: They *can*, but it's generally better if you'd use separate namespaces for separate projects.

Comment: Yes they can, but I'd also use distinct namespaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just create a Class Library project in VB, and then add a reference to that project from your C# project. (Or if it's in a different solution, add a reference to the DLL created by the VB project.) It should be absolutely fine - you'll have access to all the `Public` types from your class library.

To address the comment in your question, the projects *can* both default to the same namespace, but it's generally a better idea to make each project have its own namespace, so it's clear where any particular type comes from.

Comment: Also, be sure your VB class has a `Public` declaration: `Public Class MyClass ...`.

Comment: @chuex: Thanks, I've added something to that effect in the answer.